# MC object activity error

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm trying to create a journey and I've added the Object Activity in the flow but when I click on it I get this error. [image]

The strange thing is that even though I encounter this error in this business unit, I have no issue setting up the Object Activity in another business unit. Note that both business units are children of the same enterprise bu, so I don't think it has to do with my user permissions.

Also, I've checked this article https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000390476&type=1 and followed the instructions of the second solution, but the problem was not resolved.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If your MC account is enabled with multi-org then in that child BU, you may need to check the user permission of the integrated user

Comment: the user is an Administrator and Marketing Cloud Administrator, and has access to all BUs. is that not enough? is there another set of permissions i should check?

Comment: I mean you need to check the profile of that integrated user in your Salesforce CRM. Make sure you that user has proper permissions

Comment: oh okay thank you, I will check it